# Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation'

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0

I am using MSWord 2003 current and creating an object of Powerpoint then applying a template. on these lines i fount an exception.

> "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation'. This
>   operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component
>   for the interface with IID '{9149349D-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B}'
>   failed due to the following error: No such interface supported
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))."

```
    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation)objPresentation).Tags.Add("Carma DocSys~XML", m_Model.Document.get_Data.OuterXml);
    objMaster = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation)objPresentation).TitleMaster;
```

code is

```
        object objApplication; //As Object ' PowerPoint.Application
        object objPresentation = new object();  // As Object ' PowerPoint.Presentation
        string strTemplate;//     As String

        objApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
       strTemplate = Convert.ToString(ndModel.GetAttribute("template"));
       objPresentation ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application)objApplication).Presentations.Add();
      ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation)objPresentation).ApplyTemplate(strTemplate);

      ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation)objPresentation).Tags.Add("Carma DocSys~XML", m_Model.Document.get_Data.OuterXml);

   objMaster = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation)objPresentation).TitleMaster;
```

Comment: Why are you declaring those variables as `object`? Don't you see how terrible that looks with all that casting? Anyway, I suspect it's failing because you initialize `objPresentation` with an `object` and attempt to cast to a `Presentation`. It clearly should fail.

Comment: ok Thanks WhozCraig. let me try it.